# Reset CSS transform origin after translation / rotation

Tags: html, css, rotation, css-animations, css-transforms

After translating an element in CSS it's transformation origin stays in it's original location. In this particular case I want the transformation origin to **stay** centered relative to the element during all transforms. I want the origin to sort of *follow* the element being transformed. I know about the `transform-origin` property but that seems to require me to manually move the origin with the element each time...And even if I could do that in JavaScript, it seems very math heavy and not intuitive.

The animation below behaves exactly as intended except for the last *wide* rotation. I want that last rotation to revolve around the center of the actual element. Not it's original location. How can I move the `transform` origin back to the center of this element. Ideas?

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #fdfdfd;
  color: #aaa;
  font-family: Arial, 'sans-serif';
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.1rem;
}
.tri {
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-left: 1rem solid transparent;
  border-right: 1rem solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 1rem solid #555;
  transform: scaleY( 2 );
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.status, .instr {
  position: absolute;
}
.status {
  top: 0;
}
.instr {
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <style>
    .tri-bx {
      animation-name: start;
      animation-duration: 5s;
      animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    }
    @keyframes start {
      0% {
        transform: rotate( 0deg );
      }
      33% {
        transform: rotate( 315deg );
      }
      66% {
        transform: rotate( 315deg ) translate( 0, -5rem );
      }
      100% {
        transform: rotate( 720deg ) translate( 0, -5rem );
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="tri-bx">
    <div class="tri"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resetting the transform origin, as you say is *hard*

However, you can keep adding transforms on the right side, with the previous ones unchanged, and you'll get what you want.

(As a side note, in a snippet you don't need the body element in the HTML, and the styles are better placed in the CSS editor.)

```css
.tri-bx {
  animation-name: start;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes start {
  0% {
    transform: rotate( 0deg);
  }
  33% {
    transform: rotate( 315deg);
  }
  66% {
    transform: rotate( 315deg) translate( 0, -5rem) rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate( 315deg) translate( 0, -5rem) rotate( 405deg);
  }
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #fdfdfd;
  color: #aaa;
  font-family: Arial, 'sans-serif';
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.1rem;
}

.tri {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 1rem solid transparent;
  border-right: 1rem solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 1rem solid #555;
  transform: scaleY( 2);
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.status,
.instr {
  position: absolute;
}

.status {
  top: 0;
}

.instr {
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="tri-bx">
  <div class="tri"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow... This is amazing

Comment: Happy that it helped !

Comment: But I may have coded myself into a corner with this technique: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43723656/transforms-are-added-endlessly.